# Node.js/Gulp: child process spawn 'Error: spawn EACCES'

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am trying to build and run an executable in Gulp using Node. My executable builds fine, however attempting to run it gives this error:

> Error: spawn EACCES
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1023:11)
>       at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:313:11)
>       at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:387:9)
>       at Gulp. (/path/to/my/app/gulpfile.js:167:24)
>       at module.exports (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
>       at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
>       at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
>       at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
>       at Gulp. (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/gulp-sync/lib/index.js:51:27)
>       at module.exports (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)

Bear in mind that my script works perfectly fine when my gulpfile.js is in the same directory as the executable I am attempting to run.

But I have moved my gulpfile.js to one directory down, and in order to build/run the executable I have to change the `cwd` of the child process I am spawning to the directory above it. In doing so, even though the executable still builds fine, the running of it keeps giving me this error and I can't find any help online.

I tried to set executable permissions on the file, thinking it was a permissions problem, but that didn't do anything.

I also tried putting the logic to run the executable in a shell script and run the shell script using the child process instead (cause why not), but that didn't help either.

Here's the code:

```
// Spawn application server
if (os.platform() === 'win32') {
    // server = child.spawn(appName + '.exe') <-- USED TO WORK
    server = child.spawn(appName + '.exe', [], {
        cwd: mainDotGoPath
    });
} else {
    // server = child.spawn('./' + appName) <-- USED TO WORK
    server = child.spawn('./' + appName, [], {
        cwd: mainDotGoPath
    });
}
```

The path is fine, by the way, because I build the executable using a similar syntax and it builds just fine:

```
var build = child.spawnSync('go', ['build'], {
    cwd: mainDotGoPath
});
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `sudo`?

Comment: No but that won't be a good solution in this case because it implies everyone will have `sudo`, and surely won't be the case. I shouldn't be forced to use `sudo` here, I don't understand why it simply won't run. And if `sudo` solves the problem then that implies that there may be permissions issues, but I already attempted manipulating the permissions (successfully), to no prevail.